# Green video using Chrome on Fire 10HD tablet

Tags: chrome-for-android, video

Android 9, KFMAWI, PS7427 Chrome 113.0.5672.162

Recently, when running Chrome on my Fire 10HD tablet some videos will only display a green screen.  Audio does work.  [**Example**](https://videos.etrailer.com/static/images/video/Demo-DeeMaxx-Trailer-Bearings-Races-Seals-Caps-Stainless-Steel-Grease-Cap-with-Plug-DE79YR.webm)

I have re-installed Chrome from the Google Playstore 3 or 4 times and all of the solutions I have found don't work.

Javascript IS enabled.

Solutions say "disable hardware acceleration". I can NOT find either of those under the Advanced Settings !

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access those through the browser internal pages (e.g., through Chrome, `chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode` and `chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-encode`.  On a stock FireOS device out-of-box, there's no access to internal pages but I believe the Silk browser does have a setting for hardware accelerated page loading through the frontend configuration space.
Also note that on most reputable video players (e.g., VLC, MX Player, etc.), you can choose whether to use software- or hardware-based decoding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did NOT solve my green screen problem !

Comment: @user20278071 Are you using Chrome browser?  After the video loads, try opening a new tab and navigating to `chrome://media-internals` to see if there's any issues that stand out?  Also, try looking at `chrome://gpu`?